# in javascript, how do I store in a variable (coming from a database) that contains both quotes and apostrophes?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I access the database with this syntax `:{column_name}:` and I want to store it as a string in a javascript context. It works well using `var str = ':{column_name}:'` until the data contains apostrophes, same with quotes because the data may contain both quotes and apostrophes. I think it's impossible. What do you think?

Comment: its possible to have those. it just depends on your code how you get it there.

Comment: use [encodeuricomponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can escape both quotes and apostophes by using `\"` and `\'`. For example:

```
var str = '\' is an apostrophe and \" is a quote';
```

or

```
var str = "\' is an apostrophe and \" is a quote";
```

See the section "Special Characters" on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: In fact, you **must** escape both quotes and apostrophes like this.

Comment: Not really, `var str = 'I can write " inside two apostrophes';` is valid javascript.

Comment: Yes, right: I mean that escapping systematically is always more secure, especially when the data comes from a BD and you can't tell a priori which characters it might contain.

Comment: I can't escape quotes and apostrophes since I read from the database.

Comment: How do you fetch the data from the database, using php or something else? Please provide the code and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: just wanted to know if it was possible with javascript only to handle this kind of data into a string in order to use string functions like replace.

Comment: String functions like replace only works on strings. And if you already have a javascript-string you do not have to wory about quotes since they already are in a string. If you provide code examples it will be much easier to help you.